# How to invoke a task module on bot command msbot for Teams (Nodejs)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Is there any way that I can invoke a task module (a popup window loaded in Iframe) when user enters one of my bot commands

[image]

Any help would be thankfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to invoke a [TaskModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) from a Bot command. Task Modules can only be invoked on a Button click. Please check the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module) here.